# How to add jQuery Datepicker to image on asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I just have successfully got me a basic datepicker assigned to a input: type"text" control. The next goal is to assign the datepicker to showOn when an image is clicked. The image can be  to the left or right of the input box. I can do this in aJax controls but really trying to learn jQuery so please show thy way! I have 2 other input boxes that i will be repeating this same method for so it'll be sweet to get this up and running! So far this is my jQuery to assign the datepicker to the control

```
$(function () {
   $("input[id$='txtPreviousCutOff']").datepicker();
});
```

Note: i also want to append a time to that date, how can i do that? I'm wanting to append 12:00:00 AM to the date selected..i tried this but it fails :(

```
$(function () {
   var input = $("input[id$='txtPreviousCutOff']");
   input.val(input.val() + " " + "12:00:00 AM");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
<input id='invdate' name='invdate' type='text'/>
<span style='padding:5px'><img id='dpimage' alt="img" src='calendar2.gif'></span>

$(function() {
  $("#invdate").datepicker();
  $("#dpimage").click(function () {
    $("#invdate").datepicker("show")
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Jfq/)

Comment: I went with this method and it works flawless! I did however use part of the answer from the first response also. I used the onClose event to handle the append which works great :)

Comment: I do have another question while im at this. How can i make it not append the text on the onclose event if no date is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The Datepicker plugin has parameters for the first part, from the documentation:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

As for your second question, you will probably have more success appending on the onClose() event, the instance and the value get passed so you should be able to grab the date and append it to the time and then append it to the input.  Also make sure your ASP.net input ID isn't created dynamically.